# SQL Database code

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is to Produce a list of the top 3 most popular movies for a given genre for the current month.

How to find the top 3 most popular movies??

```
select DVD.Genre, DVD.MovieTitle, BorrowDVD.Ratings
from DVD join BorrowDVD
    ON DVD.DVDID = BorrowDVD.DVDID
WHERE DVD.Genre = Animation
```

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text.

Comment: what is the error? Can paste the table structure of DVD and BorrowDVD table please....

Comment: I added the pictures of the table

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put single quotes around the word animation:

```
WHERE DVD.Genre = 'Animation'
```

SQL thinks Animation is a column, putting quotes around it shows that it is a string to match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` method and get top 3 most popular movies :

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT * ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Movie_type) RNo
    FROM your_tablename
) WHERE RNo <= 3 -- AND your_another WHERE conditions.
```